# In Apigee, how to pass access_token to GetOAuthv2Info policy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, apigee

I'm trying to use Apigee's GetOAuthv2Info policy but think I'm missing something really simple (still new to Apigee/APIs)...

The policy is configured based on the sample:

```
<GetOAuthV2Info name="GetTokenAttributes">
  <AccessToken>request.queryParam.access_token</AccessToken>
</GetOAuthV2Info>`
```

If I try to pass a valid token via a query parameter:

http://{host}/path/to/endpoint?access_token=tUbvXzh97UtRRUuBpGUNpXESJtD1, I get a **404 Not Found** error code with:

```
{"fault":"{\"detail\":
{\"errorcode\":\"keymanagement.service.invalid_access_token\"},
\"faultstring\":\"Invalid Access Token\"}"}
```

Is this the correct way to pass the access token to the policy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<GetOAuthV2Info name="GetTokenAttributes">
  <AccessToken ref="request.queryparam.access_token"></AccessToken>
</GetOAuthV2Info>
```

or

```
<GetOAuthV2Info name="GetTokenAttributes">
  <AccessToken>{request.queryparam.access_token}</AccessToken>
</GetOAuthV2Info>
```

Your original policy is probably using the literal string value of `request.queryParam.access_token` as the token reference.  Also noticed that `queryparam` is complete lower case.